# Joining Table via Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, linked-server

I have 2 servers with 2 different databases.

S1(Server) WITH DB1(Database) WITH T1(Table)

and

S2(Server) WITH DB2(Database) WITH T2(Table)

DB1 has a linked server to S2 DB2.

So i can run a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
JOIN [S2].[DB2].[T2] T2
ON T1.[ID] = T2.[ID]
```

And this runs correctly.

However, how can i run it in the opposite direction

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM T2 
JOIN [S1].[DB1].[T1] T1
ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID]
```

This errors with **"Could not find server [S1].[DB1].[T1]"**

Is there anyway i can join in this direction without having to create a linked server from S2 to S1?

Comment: @MitchWheat absolutely no other way around it?

Comment: Which server are you running these queries on?

Comment: @SEarle1986 I am running it on S1

Comment: Both of them are running on S1?

Comment: @SEarle1986 i am running the queries on S1 but one table is on s1 and one is on s2

Comment: Sorry, I misread your second query. Gordon has the answer below. Its because SQL Server is assuming T2 is a local table. See his answer, he has re-written it fr you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T2 JOIN
     [S1].[DB1].[T1] T1
     ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID];
```

Presumes that `T2` is local.  You can sort of do a hybrid:

```
SELECT *
FROM [S2].[DB2].[T2] T2 JOIN
     [DB1].[T1] T1
     ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID];
```

It is possible to link a server to itself, so if you did that, you could run this identical query on both servers:

```
SELECT *
FROM [S2].[DB2].[T2] T2 JOIN
     [S2].[DB1].[T1] T1
     ON T2.[ID] = T1.[ID];
```

If you are trying to implement "equivalent" queries on two servers, then synonyms could help.  You might be interested in the [answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84642/creating-a-linked-server-that-points-to-itself?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is more thorough but you can rewrite your second query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM [S2].[DB2].[T2] T2
     JOIN T1
ON   T2.ID = T1.ID
```